# Gnuplot fitting not working well (Unlike KaleidaGraph)

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I am currently trying to use gnuplot to fit the a simple data set using the beneath commands, however I am having no luck despite including good initial guesses.

Commands:

```
gnuplot> f(x) = 1/(2*pi) * 1/m1 * 1/(b + x**2)**(-3/2)
gnuplot> m1 = 150
gnuplot> m2 = 17
gnuplot> fit f(x) "data.txt" using 1:2 via m1, m2
```

Data (x:y):

```
2   1.2643E-05
3   7.90515E-06
4   5.67976E-06
5   4.70381E-06
6   3.65957E-06
7   2.69824E-06
8   2.06054E-06
9   1.52311E-06
10  1.0627E-06
11  7.88733E-07
12  5.89984E-07
13  4.70111E-07
14  3.62744E-07
15  2.48113E-07
16  1.84463E-07
17  1.28446E-07
18  1.09519E-07
19  9.40524E-08
20  8.20673E-08
```

However gnuplot returns m1 = 2.45e14 and m2 = 3.64e9 which are simply incorrect and huge compared to the (roughly correct) initial values

I have tried using the exact same data set and fitting function in KaleidaGraph (demo version) which **does** return correct results (as per below picture) and could use this if gnuplot will not work, however I would prefer to use gnuplot as I will be able to automate the process for many data files then as I do not believe that KaleidaGraphs has a command line terminal.

[image: KaleidaGraph fit]

Does anyone know why gnuplot is returning such wild values?

(If it helps I'm using Windows 8.1 x64)

Many thanks for all help,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: Gnuplot does integer division, so you must use `3/2.0` to get the correct exponent.

Second, the function in gnuplot is not the same as the one used in KaleidaGraph: The exponent must be positive `(3/2.0)` and you must use `m2` where you have `b`:

```
f(x) = 1/(2*pi) * 1/m1 * 1/(m2 + x**2)**(3/2.0)
m1 = 150
m2 = 17
fit f(x) "data.txt" using 1:2 via m1,m2
```

That gives:

```
...
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================

m1              = 127.11           +/- 11.31        (8.898%)
m2              = 18.1347          +/- 1.54         (8.492%)
```

Comment: Ah yes, the B is a typo in the post but the rest is fantastic help, thank you very much!!